# blank page on adding dependency to my starter app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am new to ionic framework and trying to put the ngPDFViewer to my application. **The error I get is**:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module starter due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngPDFViewer due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ngPDFViewer' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

**What I do**

In index.html

```
<!-- ionic/angularjs js -->

<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/pdf.compat.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/pdf.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/ng-pdfviewer.js"></script>

<!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
<script src="cordova.js"></script>

<!-- your app's js -->
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="js/services.js"></script>
```

In app.js

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngPDFViewer', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services'])
```

More information about ngPDFViwer here:

https://github.com/akrennmair/ng-pdfviewer/

Comment: Have you check the path to ng-pdfviewer.js ?

Comment: @Thierry I am not sure if i am doing right, is there a way to bind the name "ngPDFViewer" to the included javascript file?

Comment: Every thing seems correct, 'ngPDFViewer' is the name of the angular module (you can see it in ng-pdfviewer.js)

Comment: The path is correct also, the file is there. Do you have other thoughts on that?

Comment: 1. Ensure you have all js files loaded correctly, 2. Double check module names, 3. try to clean cache of browser, 4. try to re-create app from scratch

Comment: try to move the cordova.js before all other js files maybe this helps, can have other sideeffects though